# What is the equivalent Google Cloud Platform product related to AWS Data Exchange

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, data-exchange

What is the equivalent Google Cloud Platform product related to AWS Data Exchange
https://aws.amazon.com/data-exchange/

Answer (score 0):

I've looked in the official Google Cloud Platform [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws#service_comparisons) that compares AWS and GCP products and they don't mention the AWS Data Exchange product at all.

So, most likely there isn't an equivalent GCP product to AWS Data Exchange.

That said, BigQuery supports [third party data transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/third-party-transfer), so maybe this is closest to what you're looking for:

> Third party transfers for BigQuery Data Transfer Service allow you to automatically schedule and manage recurring load jobs for external data sources such as Salesforce CRM, Adobe Analytics, and Facebook Ads.

Comment: I don't think there is an equivalent here, note it seems to be a marketplace for data and this has nothing to do with third party data transfer. Not sure how vendors push data into AWS Data Exchange though